# Implicit navigation in JSF2

Tags: jsf, jsf-2, html

A question about JSF 2 implicit navigation. He seeks only page in the root directory? Because I separate my pages in folders on WebContent except index.php page that I let inside the WebContent. My application service begins normally opens the index page that contains a button to the login page, the login page is in a directory called "public" which is inside the WebContent directory. When I click the button on the index page shows that he **could not find the login page**.

- I've tried to change the result of the method of the ManagedBean that directs you to the login page, looked like this: "public / login.xhtml", but neither worked.

I thank anyone who can help me.

EDIT

**ManagedBean**

```
package financeiro.web;

import javax.faces.application.FacesMessage;
import javax.faces.bean.ManagedBean;
import javax.faces.bean.RequestScoped;
import javax.faces.context.FacesContext;

import financeiro.usuario.Usuario;
import financeiro.usuario.UsuarioRN;

@ManagedBean(name = "usuarioBean")
@RequestScoped
public class UsuarioBean {

private Usuario usuario;
private String confirmarSenha;

public UsuarioBean() {
}

public String novo() {
    this.usuario = new Usuario();
    this.usuario.setAtivo(true);

    /*
     * Solution according to the Xtreme Biker. Works now. Thanks. 
     * Before: public/usuario 
     * After:  /public/usuario
     */
    return "/publico/usuario";
}

public String salvar() {
    FacesContext context = FacesContext.getCurrentInstance();

    String senha = this.usuario.getSenha();

    if (!senha.equals(this.confirmarSenha)) {
        FacesMessage facesMessage = new FacesMessage(
                "A senha não foi confirmada corretamente.");
        context.addMessage(null, facesMessage);
        return null;
    }

    UsuarioRN usuarioRN = new UsuarioRN();
    usuarioRN.salvar(usuario);

    return "usuarioSucesso";
}

public Usuario getUsuario() {
    return usuario;
}

public void setUsuario(Usuario usuario) {
    this.usuario = usuario;
}

public String getConfirmarSenha() {
    return confirmarSenha;
}

public void setConfirmarSenha(String confirmarSenha) {
    this.confirmarSenha = confirmarSenha;
}
}
```

**web.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<web-app xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee"
xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_3_0.xsd"
version="3.0">
<display-name>FinanceiroWeb</display-name>

<servlet>
    <display-name>Faces Servlet</display-name>
    <servlet-name>Faces Servlet</servlet-name>
    <servlet-class>javax.faces.webapp.FacesServlet</servlet-class>
    <load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup>
</servlet>

<servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>Faces Servlet</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern>*.xhtml</url-pattern>
</servlet-mapping>

<context-param>
    <param-name>javax.faces.PROJECT_STAGE</param-name>
    <param-value>Development</param-value>
</context-param>

<welcome-file-list>
    <welcome-file>index.html</welcome-file>
    <welcome-file>index.xhtml</welcome-file>
</welcome-file-list>

<filter>
    <filter-name>conexaoFilter</filter-name>
    <filter-class>financeiro.web.filter.ConexaoHibernateFilter</filter-class>
</filter>

<filter-mapping>
    <filter-name>conexaoFilter</filter-name>
    <url-pattern>*.xhtml</url-pattern>
</filter-mapping>
```

**index.html**

```
<meta http-equiv="Refresh" content="0;URL=publico/login.xhtml" />
```

**login.xhtml**

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml"
xmlns:h="http://java.sun.com/jsf/html"
xmlns:f="http://java.sun.com/jsf/core">
<h:head>
<title>Login</title>
</h:head>
<h:body>
<h1>Login</h1>
<hr />
<h:form>
    <h:commandButton action="#{usuarioBean.novo}" value="Registre-se" />
</h:form>
<hr />
</h:body>
</html>
```

**Directory structure of the project**

**OBS.: I use Maven Project**

Link image: http://postimg.org/image/bm7iwbmxf/

Comment: Why do you have an `index.php` page there? If working with facelets use the `*.xhtml` suffix. For the outcome, returning an absolute path as `/public/login` should work.

Comment: Your question is not clear. Please show the folder structure and the relevant code and clearly describe the use case.

Comment: Oops, on the case of the index.php page I got confused, is actually index.html

Comment: The solution of the Xtreme Biker worked. But is there any configuration for the JSF understand that there are pages in the root directory and the directory "public" without putting the absolute path as a result of the methods?

Comment: Another question, I have the following sequence of navigation: index.html -> login.xhtml -> usuario.xhtml -> usuarioSucesso.xhtml. For each transaction from one page to another, the ManagedBean UsuarioBean object is created and destroyed, just that I need to keep the same "live" object throughout the sequence of navigation I mentioned, the best way would change the scope of UsuarioBean? What scope would be appropriate?